# How to collapse column in rdlc

Tags: report, rdlc

We can use the hide property to display/hide column, but still it occupies column space

I want to collapse it same like we do in wpf, so if we don't want to see the column we can use the space for other columns.

Any solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using Textboxes inside a **List** repeater to generate the table? That's what we were doing and we had the same problem you describe.

[image: pic]

The solution was to switch to using a true **Table**. Columns in an RDLC table will collapse OK.

If you are using a **Table** are you setting the visibility of the column itself? Ensure you are setting the visibility of the entire column, not just the field.